# Add values to dynamically created object

Tags: python

I have object created like this:

```
object = eval(someClass+'()')
```

now i have for loop with all fileds:

```
for f in eval(someClass+"._meta.fields"):
```

How can I, add data to all object fields?

`someClass` is a string.

Comment: because i'm new in python and know only this way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eval()` when you have [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
cls = globals()[someClass]
instance = cls()
for f in cls._meta.fields:
    previous_value = getattr(instance, f)
    setattr(instance, f, previous_value + 'some new value')
```

I avoided the use of `object` as a variable name; it would mask the built-in [`object()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object).